# Why does the 'couldn't read cache at: .cache-<My Username> ' warning appear and the code run indefinitely when authenticating in Spotipy?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, spotipy

I'm trying to access my liked songs using spotipy in Google Colab using the code below:

```
import spotipy 
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

# credentials
cid ='<My Client ID>'
secret = '<My Client Secret>'
username = '<My Username>'
scope = 'user-library-read'
redirect_uri='http://localhost:8888/callback/'

# access user
client_credentials_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(
    scope=scope,
    username=username,
    client_id=cid,
     client_secret=secret,
     redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

# a user saved song
sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=1)
```

However whenever I run it I'm returned with 'couldn't read cache at: .cache-'my username' and the code runs indefinitely. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the browser cannot open in Google Colab so they could runs indefinitely to solve this set `open_browser=False` and it will open in a new tab and all will work fine. The couldn't read cache warning will disappear after the first run.

```
import spotipy 
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

# credentials
cid ='<My Client ID>'
secret = '<My Client Secret>'
username = '<My Username>'
scope = 'user-library-read'
redirect_uri='http://localhost:8888/callback/'

# access user
client_credentials_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(
    scope=scope,
    username=username,
    client_id=cid,
     client_secret=secret,
      redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
      open_browser=False)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

# a user saved song
sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=1)
```